# SQL that matches all or nothing

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have the following table in PostgreSQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE maclist (
    username character varying,
    mac macaddr NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT maclist_user_mac_key UNIQUE (username, mac)
);
```

I need a way to check if the MAC address is assigned to the user or the user has no assigned MAC addresses at all. Basically I need a query that returns row if all conditions are true or no condition is true ie **NOT a XOR b**.

**EDIT:**
Example:

```
username | mac
john     | 11:22:33:44:55:66
john     | 11:22:33:44:55:67
doe      | 11:22:33:44:55:68
```

If I query:

```
username = john, mac = 11:22:33:44:55:66                     -> true, 1 whatever...
username = john, mac != 11:22:33:44:55:66                    -> 0, null or nothing...
username = jane, mac = no matter what except john's or doe's -> true, 1 whatever...
username = jane, mac = john's or doe's                       ->  0, null or nothing...
```

I need `true` under two conditions:

1. There is a row for that (user, mac) combination. There are no rows
2. for that user AND there are no rows for that mac

So far I got this:

```
SELECT yes
FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS yes) AS dummy
LEFT JOIN maclist ON (username = 'user'
                      OR mac = '11:22:33:44:55:66')
WHERE ((username = 'user'
        AND mac = '11:22:33:44:55:66')
       OR (username IS NULL
           AND mac IS NULL);
```

It works, but it seems to me like a hack and I also have no idea about the performance of this query as the database grows.
My question is if there are any better ways to do this.

Comment: Please could you *explicitly* write out the conditions under which you need the result to be *true*?  Perhaps a logic table?  Or just a bullet list of scenarios that result in *true*?

Comment: Can two users ever share the same mac address?  *(In a real life situation multiple users connect from multiple mac addresses, and mac addresses have multiple users connect from them.)*

Comment: True, so you can add more than one MAC per user. The constraint in the table is on both fields, so user is not unique and if user is `NULL` this counts as blacklisted MAC (at least this is the idea)

Comment: So, you only want `true` under two conditions? `1.` There is a row for that (user, mac) combination. `2.` There are no rows for that user AND there are no rows for that mac?

Comment: Yes. This is the idea. Sorry! English is not my native language.

Comment: Your English is so good that I didn't even realise it's not your first language.  I'm looking at this for you, between scripts that I'm running :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: *I've revised the logic slightly, I think it matches what you want***

The following code will return `1` under two conditions...

- There is a row for that `user` and that `mac`
- There are `0` rows for that user ***and*** there are `0` rows for that `mac`

Under all other conditions, the query returns `0`.

- There are rows for that `user` but none of them are for that `mac`
- There are rows for that `mac`  but none of them are for that `user`

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0                                THEN 1
       WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN mac = '11:22:33:44:55:66'
                      AND user = 'user' THEN 1
                                        ELSE 0 END) = 1 THEN 1
                                                        ELSE 0
  END
FROM
  maclist
WHERE
     username = 'user'
  OR mac      = '11:22:33:44:55:66'
```

Comment: I'll use your solution, but I'll replace the odd nested `CASE ... WHEN` with `COALESCE(SUM(CAST(mac = '11:22:33:44:55:66' AND username = 'user' AS integer)), 1)` which even seems to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the query simply as:

```
prepare query_mac(text, macaddr) as
select exists (select 1 from maclist where username = $1 and mac = $2)
       or (not exists (select 1 from maclist where username = $1)
           and not exists (select 1 from maclist where mac = $2)
          );
```

PostgreSQL will evaluate each of the three queries separately, and use the unique index on `(username,mac)` for the first two. If you need to, you can add an index on `(mac)` for the third.

Answer (score 0):

Practically all databases won't use an index when an `OR` is involved, so avoid those in the joins.

#### Edited:

It seems you are really making two separate queries:

- who is the mac assigned to (if any)
- what mac is assigned to the user (if any)

so a union won't be as easy as a collection of subselects. Use separate queries to split up the info into their own simple query, and combine them into one:

```
select
    (select username from maclist
     where mac = '11.22:33:44:55:66') as mac_assigned_to,
    (select mac from maclist
     where username = 'user') as user_assigned_to
```

Both columns may have nulls if there is nothing currently assigned, otherwise they'll show what's assigned for each concern.

Comment: I like the UNION idea. I didn't guessed that, but I need negatived exclusive OR. So if other have this MAC i must not use it.

Comment: @core1024 - What do you mean by the last statement?  `So if other have this MAC i can't use it.`

Comment: **ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression** You didn't get it at all. araqnid's and Dems'  answers do what's supposed to be done.